# Is there a way to ignore only one field (BLOB) from a entity object during fetch using SPRING JPA Repo

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

While using Spring JPA and trying to fetch an entity from the DB which contains a **blob**, it takes a long time to load if the result set is large.

Is there a way I can ignore just only one attribute of the entity, i.e the **blob** while fetching the data using SPRING JPA? For example, `repo.findAll()` or

```
Example<EnityVO> siloQueryExample= Example.of(entityVO);
List<EnityVO> queryResult = imageSiloRepo.findAll(siloQueryExample,sort);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can anotate your blob column with

`@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)`

This way your column is marked to be lazy loaded, which means your blob will only be fetched upon explicitly calling it with getter.

Comment: I have tried this, still, the response is taking a long time. I know I could use jdbcTemplate.query, like  List<DashBoardVO> list = jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery.toString(),new DashBoardRowMapper());  but wanted to find out is there any way using annotation to just fetch the required columns

Comment: Are you sure the slowness is caused by blob field after you have put annotation? Can you post entire mapping of the EnityVO? If you want to fetch only selected columns you should use projections like MartinBG has answered.

Comment: Added the EntityVO to the original comment pls check above

Answer (score 1):

You could use [projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) to fetch only required columns. Here are some tutorials:

- [Spring Data JPA Projections](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections)
- [Why, When and How to Use DTO Projections with JPA and Hibernate](https://thoughts-on-java.org/dto-projections/)

Another solution is [to map multiple JPA entities to one database table](https://vladmihalcea.com/map-multiple-jpa-entities-one-table-hibernate/) - one with all columns and another without the **blob** one. Here is another tutorial:

- [How to Map Multiple Entities to the Same Table](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-map-multiple-entities-same-table/)

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried Projections in my project and it works